# I don't want url #hash to be in the url after submitting the form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, hash, form-submit

update: **In this case `action="url.php"` works as I desired**

When I submit a form (I use get method), the url #hash part also got appended to the end of url after submit of the form. I tried to change the action of the page to get rid of this url #hash from the string. I removed the action part from the form, provided action as action="url.php", provided action as action="url.php#", but nothing helped me to get rid of the URL #hash after submitting the form. Is there any way to get rid of this url #hash after submitting the form?

I use jQuery.

Comment: But how are you sending it? Show the code.

Comment: Oops! In this case action="url.php" works as I desired, but by mistake I edited the wrong file (there is another similar file in my code base). Now I found my mistake. Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I know what you mean, but you could try using a POST action rather than GET.
This will shift form data out of the URL.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<!--stuff in here -->
</form>
```

another thought, if you are submitting the form via jQuery and using the click handler of an anchor tag, try making sure you `'return false'`, or try using a submit button and catching `$("#myForm").submit()` instead

Answer (score 0):

If your form action does not include the hash, it seems that there is some onsubmit handler which adds it again. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use exact url with: `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` and `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` variables.

**Sample usage:**

`<form action="http://<?=$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?>" method="post">`